# Amazon API Product Description

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services

I searched for a solution for hours, but came up with nothing.
I am trying to get a products description via Amazon API using their PHP/SOAP class.
It does work but for some products, it looks like there are multiple (2) entries for product description. 
e.g. this URL:

http://www.amazon.de/Nintendo-3DS-Konsole-Aqua-Blau/dp/B003SE6TPA/ref=acc_glance_vg_ai_ps_t_1
You can see a very detailed one with images and stuff and a very short, one line description at the bottom. 
The Amazon API does only return the short description to me.
Anyone knows a way to get around this and to retrieve the full description ?

Answer (score 9):

There is no technical fault; it is a copyright issue. Amazon purchases the product description from third parties for many of the products. For these descriptions, it is not allowed to distribute through the AWS API.

The best Amazon support discussion thread on the copyright issue:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=16331&tstart=0